# Writing grib1 files with R

Tags: r, grib

I am manipulating some grib1 raster files in R and I have to write those rasters in the grib1 file format to the harddisk again. Is there a function to do so? I have checked the `rNOMADS` package but can only find function to read grib files. `writeRaster` has no option to write grib files either.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I know a solution with python: 
1. Install [cfgrib](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib) and xarray
2.:

```
import xarray
import cfgrib
data = xarray.open_dataset('filename.grb', engine='cfgrib')
data.t2m += 273.15
cfgrib.to_grib(data, 'out1.grib', grib_keys={'edition': 2})
```

I hope this is suitable for you.